# SQL query doesn't work when used in prepared statement but does in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a News-Website where you can add news if you're logged in. The news are to be sent to a MySQL Database and from there I want them to be displayed on the website.

The problem is that although my prepared statement is beeing executed and all the variables are filled with the right values, the data doesn't get written to the SQL table.

Using the same query, not as a prepared statement but with the values typed out works correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>News hinzufügen</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="add_news.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titel" class="titlestyle" required="required">
        <select name="kategorie" class="kategoriestyle">
            <option value="1">Kategorie 1</option>
            <option value="2">Kategorie 2</option>
            <option value="3">Kategorie 3</option>
        </select>
        Gültig von <input type="date" name="vondate"> bis <input type="date" name="bisdate" required="required">
        <textarea name="news" class="textareastyle" required="required">    
        </textarea>
        <input type="file" name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload">
        <input type="text" name="bildbeschreibung" placeholder="Beschreiben Sie Ihr Bild"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Link">
        <input type="text" name="linkbeschreibung" placeholder="Beschreiben Sie Ihren Link" > <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Fertigstellen" class="submitstyle">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

The echos are just checkpoints so that I see what was executed and what wasn't.

```
<?php session_start();  ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<?php
$dbserver = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbpassword = '';
$dbname = 'm151db';
$titel = "";
$text = "";
$kategorie;
$vondatum = "";
$bidatum = "";
$bild = "";
$bildbeschr = "";
$link = "";
$linkbeschr = "";


$autor = $_SESSION["username"];
$error = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die('Connection Error: Es gab ein Problem mit dem Verbindungsaufbau. ('.$conn->connect_errno.')'.$conn->connect_error);
        } 


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO news (name, beschreibung, kategorie_id, von, bis, bild, bildbeschreibung, link, linkbeschreibung, author) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $titel, $text, $kategorie, $vondatum, $bisdatum, $bild, $bildbeschr, $link, $linkbeschr, $autor);

        if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
            $titel = trim($_POST['title']);
            echo "$titel";

        }

        if(isset($_POST['news'])) {
            $text = trim($_POST['news']);
            echo "$text";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['kategorie'])) {
            $katerorie = $_POST['kategorie'];
            echo "$kategorie";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['vondate'])) {
            $vondatum = $_POST['vondate'];
            echo "$vondatum";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['bisdate'])) {
            $bisdatum = $_POST['bisdate'];
            echo "$bisdatum";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['bildbeschreibung'])) {
            $bildbeschr = trim($_POST['bildbeschreibung']);
            echo "$bildbeschr";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['link'])) {
            $link = trim($_POST['link']);
            echo "$link";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['linkbeschreibung'])) {
            $linkbeschr = trim($_POST['linkbeschreibung']);
            echo "$linkbeschr";
        }






    if(isset($_FILES['imageUpload'])) {

        echo "0";

        $target_dir = "uploads/";

        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);

        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));



            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

            if($check == true) {

                $uploadOk = 1;
                echo "1";
            }

            else {  ?>
                <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Es können nur Bilddateien hochgeladen werden.
                </div>
        <?php       $uploadOk = 0;
            }


        if(file_exists($target_file)) { ?>
            <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Dieses Bild wurde bereits hochgeladen.
                </div>
        <?php   $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($_FILES["imageUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {  ?>
            <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Das Bild ist zu gross. Wähle ein Bild unter 500kb aus.
                </div>
        <?php   $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") { ?>
            <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Wähle ein PNG-/JPG-/JPEG-Bild aus.
                </div>
        <?php   $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($uploadOk == 0) {  ?>
            <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Es ist ein Fehler beim hochladen ihres Bildes aufgetreten. Versuchen sie es erneut.
                </div>
        <?php 
        }
        else {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                //echo "The file has been uploaded.";
            }
            else {   ?>
                <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Es ist ein Fehler beim hochladen ihres Bildes aufgetreten. Versuchen sie es erneut.
                </div>
            <?php }





            $bild = $target_file;
            echo "$bild";
        }


    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt == true) {

            echo "stmt executed";
        }

        else {
            echo "stmt not executed";

        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Why do you bind the data before filling the variables?

Comment: @NicoHaase possibly a stylistic decision. It should not change anything however, [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) shows that the variables are passed by reference, so changing them after the binding but before execution should be correct.

Comment: Have you tried checking for errors through `$conn->error`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are inserting empty data, so it is not inserting in the table. Try defining your variables before:

```
<?php session_start();  ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<?php
$dbserver = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbpassword = '';
$dbname = 'm151db';
$titel = "";
$text = "";
$kategorie;
$vondatum = "";
$bidatum = "";
$bild = "";
$bildbeschr = "";
$link = "";
$linkbeschr = "";


$autor = $_SESSION["username"];
$error = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        # First define your variables

        if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
            $titel = trim($_POST['title']);
            echo "$titel";

        }

        if(isset($_POST['news'])) {
            $text = trim($_POST['news']);
            echo "$text";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['kategorie'])) {
            $katerorie = $_POST['kategorie'];
            echo "$kategorie";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['vondate'])) {
            $vondatum = $_POST['vondate'];
            echo "$vondatum";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['bisdate'])) {
            $bisdatum = $_POST['bisdate'];
            echo "$bisdatum";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['bildbeschreibung'])) {
            $bildbeschr = trim($_POST['bildbeschreibung']);
            echo "$bildbeschr";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['link'])) {
            $link = trim($_POST['link']);
            echo "$link";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['linkbeschreibung'])) {
            $linkbeschr = trim($_POST['linkbeschreibung']);
            echo "$linkbeschr";
        }

        # then prepare the statement

        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die('Connection Error: Es gab ein Problem mit dem Verbindungsaufbau. ('.$conn->connect_errno.')'.$conn->connect_error);
        } 


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO news (name, beschreibung, kategorie_id, von, bis, bild, bildbeschreibung, link, linkbeschreibung, author) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $titel, $text, $kategorie, $vondatum, $bisdatum, $bild, $bildbeschr, $link, $linkbeschr, $autor);








    if(isset($_FILES['imageUpload'])) {

        echo "0";

        $target_dir = "uploads/";

        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);

        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));



            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

            if($check == true) {

                $uploadOk = 1;
                echo "1";
            }

            else {  ?>
                <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Es können nur Bilddateien hochgeladen werden.
                </div>
        <?php       $uploadOk = 0;
            }


        if(file_exists($target_file)) { ?>
            <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Dieses Bild wurde bereits hochgeladen.
                </div>
        <?php   $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($_FILES["imageUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {  ?>
            <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Das Bild ist zu gross. Wähle ein Bild unter 500kb aus.
                </div>
        <?php   $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") { ?>
            <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Wähle ein PNG-/JPG-/JPEG-Bild aus.
                </div>
        <?php   $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($uploadOk == 0) {  ?>
            <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Es ist ein Fehler beim hochladen ihres Bildes aufgetreten. Versuchen sie es erneut.
                </div>
        <?php 
        }
        else {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                //echo "The file has been uploaded.";
            }
            else {   ?>
                <div class="alertbox">
                <span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
                Es ist ein Fehler beim hochladen ihres Bildes aufgetreten. Versuchen sie es erneut.
                </div>
            <?php }





            $bild = $target_file;
            echo "$bild";
        }


    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt == true) {

            echo "stmt executed";
        }

        else {
            echo "stmt not executed";

        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The order in which the statement is prepared is irrelevant however. As long as the correct values are written to the variables before the statement's execution, they will be correctly inserted.